# What's a good method for user to retrieve their unique identifiers?

Tags: identity-management

This is an identity management question.

After generating a unique identifier for users, what is the best way to allow them to retrieve their own uid for the first time?  They get their uid shared with them during training but they often forget.  The only unique identifier we have that they know is SSN which we don't want to use.

I have some ideas but I want to see what other IAM professionals are doing for other companies.